# Can I go into developer mode on Chrome and see the backend code?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to find out where the in-house organization also gets the data from but I don't have the backend code.
So, can I go into dev mode on Chrome and see the backend code?
As far as I'm concerned, it seems impossible.
However, I ask questions to see if there is a good way.

I analyzed the event listener function and confirmed sending a POST request to a specific url on the backend server. However, it was impossible to infer which logic it was with only url.

Comment: Unless the code is open source and available somewhere on the internet you cannot view it. Even from the Chrome developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge we can not view the back end code